# In Mercurial, after "hg init" to create a project and pushing onto server, how to make local directory to have "hg path" of the server?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

When a project is started with

```
mkdir proj
cd proj
hg init
[create some files]
hg add file.txt
hg commit
hg push ssh://me@somewhere.somehost.com/proj
```

now when `hg path` is issued, nothing will show.  How do we actually change the repository so that it is as if it is cloned from `me@somewhere.somehost.com/proj` ?  Is it just by editing .hg/hgrc and adding

```
[paths]
default = ssh://me@somewhere.somehost.com/proj
```

because that feels like too low level an operation to do (by editing a text file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the only way to do it in this situation.  There are plenty of other cases where you have to edit the `hgrc` by hand, like setting up hooks or enabling extensions, so it's not as if it's unusual.

(As you probably already know, `hg clone` will set the path entry in the clone to point back to the original.)

Comment: Here's Mercurial's primary author on the subject:  http://twitter.com/mpmselenic/status/8392230762